# How to track duration of request in TIBCO BusinessWorks 6

Tags: tibco, businessworks, tibco-business-works

I want to send telemetry data of my BusinessWorks 6 flow to Azure's Application Insights. They provide a java library that is easy enough to use but it requires me to fill in certain data by myself. 
Specifically I need to enter the duration of the request. While this should be easy enough to calculate I can't figure out where I can find the timestamp of the initiation of the process or any other timestamps for that matter.

My current approach is to assign the current timestamp to a variable in the start of the flow. Then at the end I use that value to calculate the duration. While it does work it results in duration times much lower then what Postman produces for instance.

Does anyone know of a simpler way I can determine the duration of a request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far i understood you want to track the duration of a request served by a businessworks process.

Afaik no easy way to find that as a variable inside the process context.

If you only like to track performance of your processes with application insights and don't need any correlation of the data processed, the process execution statistics might be thing to take a look:

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.4.1/doc/html/GUID-B07A14A8-83DF-43E4-B73D-F942103FAA1E.html

Comment: This is a very good approach for my Application Insights issue. Just need to figure out how I can add a new appender.